# How to find bottleneck in geth sync?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to benchmark geth full sync. Here are my current machine specs:

- Google Cloud
- 16 vCPU
- 14 Gb RAM
- 700 Gb NVMe SSD RAID 0
- 772k read/258k write IOPS
- 6+ Gbps network

Launching with following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  geth:
    image: ethereum/client-go
    command: "--syncmode full --nat=extip:x.x.x.x --cache=12288 --nousb"
    restart: always
    stop_grace_period: 4m
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    ports:
      - 30303:30303
    volumes:
      - /mnt/disks/ssd:/root/.ethereum
```

So far none of the resources seem to be maxed out:

- loadavg 3/16
- network 0.3/750 MB/s
- iops (r+w) 20/1000000

The machine appears to be mostly idle. How do I find out what is currently limiting sync speed?

Current speed at block 2M is ~300 blocks/sec

Comment: You can try asking them too at https://discordapp.com/invite/nthXNEv

Comment: It turned out that it is mostly bottlenecked by a single core CPU performance since transactions are inherently sequential. Some part of it is of course parallelizable, but some some parts are not.